# ASP.NET Core 6 - Use URI's extension to get Accept header value

Tags: rest, asp.net-core

I'm migrating an application from NancyFx to Kestrel in ASP.NET Core 6.

In Nancy, you could specify the Accept value in the URI. For example, these Uris:

- http://localhost:5000/my/resource.json
- http://localhost:5000/my/resource.protobuf
- http://localhost:5000/my/resource.xml

Would be the equivalent of setting the Accepts header to `application/json`, `application/protobuf` or `application/xml` respectively.

Does this exist in Kestrel? I remember finding one example, long ago, of regex-ing the route and doing it somewhat manually. But

1. I can't find that post again, and
2. If I have to do that, I'm not sure I want to :)

Is there a way to configure this behavior in ASP.NET Core 6?

The object returned from my handler in the controller is already capable of being serialized to json/xml/whatever. I just need to check the URI to set the content-type of the response so the correct formatter will be invoked.

At the moment, I have a client that will speak to both Nancy and Kestrel and it was written to use the URI to get the type. I'm fine to rewrite/update the client so it will use the Accept header. But getting the URI method to work will make the initial integration easier and a refactor to use the headers can come next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a very simple middleware that reads the `accept` value from the query string and sets the `Accept` header to the request:

```cs
public class AcceptHeaderFromQueryString
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AcceptHeaderFromQueryString(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var accept = context.Request.Query["accept"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accept))
        {
            context.Request.Headers.Accept = accept;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Register the middleware:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<AcceptHeaderFromQueryString>();
```

I added `[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml)]` attribute to my api controller action **(this step is not required)**:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml)]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

Finally I added support for xml serialization in `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Then I tried these urls and they both gave appropriate response:

> https://localhost:7258/weatherforecast?accept=application/json

> https://localhost:7258/weatherforecast?accept=application/xml

Comment: Outstanding! I was researching Middleware as a way to modify the request vs finding a configuration to do it. Your example was excellent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You possibly want the [[Consumes] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#consumes). This allows you to specify a controller action that only gets called from a route of the specified content type.

Obviously this is not using the Accepts header but the content type of the request.

Comment: Ah, this is great to know! It looks like it's mainly for incoming payloads. I need similar behavior on the GET side. However, this has given me something to look at...